# How to reverse IP to domain and get domains on the same server ?

Tags: php, reverse-dns

I'm working on a small PHP website/script, and as one of the features I'd like to be able to run a Reverse IP Domain Check on the current domain the PHP script is running on. I don't know much about Reverse (well, I know what they do, I just don't know how to run them in PHP) Please let me know how to do it and get same result as : http://www.ipfingerprints.com/reverseip.php

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use that function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

To get something more you probably should play with functions like "system" and unix tools like "host" command and parse thier output.

Or directly query the DNS - you can read here more about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup - basically you're doing a query for domain that looks like this:

`5.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa` where `5.2.0.192` should be replaced with address you're intrested in.